# How to push the process running status in centos machine using telegraf?

Tags: plugins, process, influxdb, telegraf

I am trying to monitor the **running process in my machine**.
To achieve this i leveraged  **Telegraf, Influxdb, Grafana**
In telegraf I used procstat plugin and i used the **tag procstat_lookup**
My telegraf conf file:

```
[[inputs.procstat]]
  pid_tag = true
  exe = ""
  systemd_unit = "sshd"

[[inputs.procstat]]
   pid_tag = true
   exe = ""
   systemd_unit = "influxd"
```

When i run the query Select * from procstat_lookup  where  time >= now() - 120s in Ubuntu Machine I get the output:
time                                     exe pattern    pid_count pid_finder result  result_code running

```
systemd_unit
----                                             ---               ------- --------- ---------- ------  ----------- ------- ------------
1569906900000000000                             1         pgrep      success 0           1       apache2
1569906900000000000                             1         pgrep      success 0           1       sshd
```

But when i run the same query in Centos Machine I get the output:

```
time                pid_count systemd_unit
----                --------- ------------
1569909600000000000 1         apache2
1569909600000000000 1         sshd
```

I wonder why there is a different output for the same configuration in the two different OS

Comment: Even more interesting: your influxd unit seems to start an apache webserver...

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Telegraf will pull the metric based on the OS..
If not so why for same query and same config runninig status is not pushing